# How would I synthesize ethyl 2‐oxocyclohexane‐1‐carboxylate from cyclohexanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aldol-reaction, enolate-chemistry

[image: ethyl 2‐oxocyclohexane‐1‐carboxylate from cyclohexanone]

I thought the 1st step would be deprotonation of a H atom to form the enolate. Then an aldol reaction, but the product I end up with is the alcohol, not the ketone.

Comment: Well, you need suitable reagent, to get such product...

Comment: Read this: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01853a065.

Comment: You could use ethyl chloroformate (EtOC(O)Cl) to make the desired product, I would suggest that you react the cyclohexanone with sodium ethoxide in cold ethanol before adding the electrophile to it.

Answer (score 1):

As you will see if you look at the reference mentioned by @Mathew-Mahindaratne,   the standard conditions for this transformation is NaH/KH in THF at reflux with diethyl carbonate (EtOCOOEt) with an acetic acid workup.

The Organic Syntheses procedure [here](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV7P0351) uses dimethyl carbonate, but will be equally applicable for diethyl carbonate.

Comment: Diethyl carbonate can be sluggish in this reaction. The classic procedure is to use the more reactive diethyl oxalate instead and then decarbonylate carbon monoxide from the codensation product by heating over crushed soft glass. This reaction was discovered by taking the melting point of a solid condensation product in a soft glass melting point capillary.